# Query To Get Orders By First Time Customers By A Given Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

We have an order table like this.

```
   |OrderID| CustomerID|OrderedDate|
   |-------|----------|-----------| 
   |1      | 1000      |2024-02-27 20:00:00|
   |2      | 2000      |2024-02-28 23:00:00|
   |3      | 3000      |2024-02-28 23:01:00|
   |4      | 1000      |2024-02-29 23:01:00|
   |5      | 4000      |2024-02-29 23:02:00|
```

How do we get the list of customers that placed an order for the first time after a given date?

In the example above, trying to get all the customers who placed their first order on or after `2024-02-28 23:00:00`. In this case, I am hoping to see 2000, 3000, 4000 as the results but not 1000 - because that is not a first time customer, by that date.

It seems like a simple enough task, but it is confusing when I attempt `CROSS APPLY`, `RANK` etc.

Desired result:

| CustomerId |
| --- |
| 2000 |
| 3000 |
| 4000 |

Comment: Try: `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate < '2024-02-28 23:00:00')`

Comment: 1) Please show us your desired results. 2) Please show us your closest attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the example above, trying to get all the customers who placed their first order on or after 2024-02-28 23:00:00.

Your desired result is just a list of customer ids.   Start with that.   That means you need to do some sort of grouping, or use 'Distinct' since you want one row per customer instead of one row per order.

```sql
select CustomerId
from [Order]
group by CustomerId
```

Here you care about the first order, so you can use `min(OrderedDate)` to find that and report it for each `CustomerId`:

```sql
select CustomerId, min(OrderedDate) as FirstOrderedDate
from [Order]
group by CustomerId
```

You can use a HAVING clause much like a WHERE clause to filter grouped results based on aggregate functions:

```sql
select CustomerId
from [Order]
group by CustomerId
having min(OrderedDate) >= '2024-02-28 23:00:00'
```

HAVING is much like WHERE, but WHERE filters individual rows *before* grouping, HAVING filters the grouped results *after* the grouping and only works with aggregate functions.  For instance if you wanted all customers that have only placed a single order and show the date of the order it would look like this (min or max works since there will be a single order):

```
select CustomerId, min(OrderedDate) as OrderedDate
from [Order]
group by CustomerId
having count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-query or CTE, but that requires two calls to the table. Below are two options, one being a CTE, while the 2nd option uses a windows function and should be more efficient.

```
--Using CTE, but calls table twice (less efficient)
with first_orders as (
  select customerId, min(orderedDate) as min_dt
  from orders
  group by customerId
  )
select o.*
  from orders o
  join first_orders f
    on o.customerId = f.customerId
where f.min_dt >= '2024-02-28';
```

| orderId | customerId | orderedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2000 | 2024-02-28 |
| 3 | 3000 | 2024-02-28 |
| 5 | 4000 | 2024-02-29 |

```
--Using windows function, calls table just once
select 
 orderId, customerId, orderedDate
from (
  select *, 
   min(orderedDate) over (partition by customerId) as min_dt
  from orders
  )z
where min_dt >= '2024-02-28'
order by customerId;
```

| orderId | customerId | orderedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2000 | 2024-02-28 |
| 3 | 3000 | 2024-02-28 |
| 5 | 4000 | 2024-02-29 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YKhV2myf)

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested,

```
Select * from(
SELECT *,Row_Number()over(partition by Customerid order by orderdate)rownum FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate > '2024-02-28 23:00:00')
)t where rownum=1



Select * from(
    SELECT *,Row_Number()over(partition by Customerid order by orderdate)rownum FROM Orders )
    )t where rownum=1 and OrderDate > '2024-02-28 23:00:00'
```

Comment: Does not return desired output. Move the WHERE criteria to the outer query `WHERE rownum=1 AND OrderedDate >= '2024-02-28 23:00:00'`. Also, remove the extra ) in front of t.